# ARKit – Environment Occlusion

Tags: swift, unity-game-engine, swiftui, arkit, realitykit

In Unity we can implement occlusion with [Environment Depth](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arkit@4.1/manual/arkit-occlusion.html). Which uses ARKit behind the scene. How can I achieve same behaviour in iOS ARkit.

I know we can configure frame semantics with depth, but I doubt it is really same as unity environment depth occlusion?

```
// Build the set of required frame semantics.
let semantics: ARConfiguration.FrameSemantics = [.sceneDepth]
configuration.frameSemantics = semantics

session.run(configuration)
```

Answer (score 5):

In ARKit implement `sceneReconstruction` option, and in RealityKit turn on `.occlusion`.

The only drawback is an ugly mask with soft dilated edges around real-world objects...

```
import RealityKit
import SwiftUI
import ARKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        return ARContainer().ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct ARContainer: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {  
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        arView.cameraMode = .ar
                
        arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = false
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        config.sceneReconstruction = .mesh
        arView.session.run(config)

        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options = .occlusion

        let box: MeshResource = .generateBox(size: 0.5)
        let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .green, isMetallic: true)
        let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: box, materials: [material])
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0,0,-1.5])
        anchor.addChild(entity)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)            
        return arView
    }       
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

Comment: But this only occlude persons, not other objects. I want to implement object occlusion as well.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, Can this be achieved with Scenekit?

Comment: People Occlusion – yes, Object Occlusion – must be implemented by you (it's not easy).  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/camera_lighting_and_effects/effecting_people_occlusion_in_custom_renderers

Comment: I implemented it like this
https://github.com/haris008/SceneKit-Occlusion